# Константный параметр в шаблоне по умолчанию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Подскажите в чем ошибка при реализации следующей ситуации:

Есть 2 класса дробей, сущность которых идентична за исключением некоторых особенностей, зависящих от флага "сократимые дроби"/"не сократимые дроби". По умолчанию дроби сократимые, поэтому класс задаю так:

```
template <bool isReduced = false>
class CFraction
{
public:
    int     m_numenator;
    int     m_denumenator;

public:
    // конструкторы
    template <bool isReduced = false>
    CFraction()
        : m_numenator(0), m_denumenator(1)
    {}

    template <bool isReduced = false>
    CFraction(const int numenator)
        : m_numenator(numenator), m_denumenator(1)
    {}

    template <bool isReduced = false>
    CFraction(const int numenator, const int denumenator)
        : m_numenator(numenator), m_denumenator(denumenator)
    {}
};
```

во первых при попытке

```
const CFraction num(1, 3);
```

сразу выдаётся ошибка

> Error C2955   'CFraction': use of class template requires template
>   argument list fractions
>
> Error C2514   'CFraction': class has no
>   constructors  fractions

Почему так?

И второй вопрос - для сравнения использую такой код (код работал, но потом я как раз стал переходить на шаблоны :))

```
template <bool isReduced = false>
    friend bool operator == (const CFraction& val1, const CFraction& val2)
    {
        return (CFraction<true>(CFraction(val1) - CFraction(val2)).m_numenator == 0);
    }
```

тут вопрос такой - а как показать в параметрах метода, что параметр шаблона у этих параметров могут быть любые, меня они не интересуют, т.е.

```
friend bool operator == (const CFraction<any>& val1, const CFraction<any>& val2)
```

иначе это будет восприниматься как `isReduced = false`, а этого хотелось бы избежать

Еще раз оговорю - решил делать через шаблоны, поскольку сущности дробей сократимых и несократимых одинаковы и отличия лишь в конвертации одних в другие после завершения операций

Comment: Вы написали шаблон с параметром. Почему же вы его используете без параметра?

Comment: @Ant, исправился (ниже описал), но вот такая вещь `template <bool T1, bool T2>  friend CFraction operator + (const CFraction<T1>& value1, const CFraction<T2>& value2) {return CFraction(...);}` выдает ошибку `Error C2593 'operator +' is ambiguous`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем вообще у вас при конструкторах?

```
template <bool isReduced = false>
class CFraction
{
public:
    int     m_numenator;
    int     m_denumenator;

public:
    // конструкторы
    CFraction()
        : m_numenator(0), m_denumenator(1)
    {}

    CFraction(const int numenator)
        : m_numenator(numenator), m_denumenator(1)
    {}

    CFraction(const int numenator, const int denumenator)
        : m_numenator(numenator), m_denumenator(denumenator)
    {}
};
```

вполне [достаточно](https://ideone.com/iAJiPe).

По второй части - см. там же. Просто делаете обычный шаблонный друг

```
template <bool T>
friend bool operator == (const CFraction<T>& val1, const CFraction<T>& val2)
```

(Кстати, у вас оператор `-` не определен, так что тело друга пришлось упростить :))

А что до

```
const CFraction<> num(1, 3);
```

то поставьте `<>`, чтобы было понятно, что это шаблон. Наверное, ваш компилятор несколько староват (или вы не попросили его поддерживать последний стандарт).

*"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*

Comment: спасибо, все попробую. Касательно компилятора - Visual Studio 2017 :) Касательно минуса - просто не стал приводить уж весь код, чтоб не запутывать лишний раз

Comment: @Zhihar А ключик `/std:` какой?

Comment: никакой, сейчас поставил `/std:c++latest` и все равно `<>` приходится ставить :(

Comment: Странно. Мой 19.16.27034 разрешает `<>` не ставить...

Comment: Указывать `<>` обязательно. Стандартный С++ не позволяет их опускать. Так что никакого "компилятор староват" тут нет. Избежать указания `<>` могут помочь только deduction guides, но их в данном примере нет.

Comment: @AnT Ну, я ждал чего-то подобного от скрупулезного знатока стандартов, потому и написал свое *"По-моему, так". (с) Пух*. У меня же, как у человека более практических наук, чем теоретических, одной из любимых книг была ***Im**perfect C++* :), так что мне достаточно знания того, что указания стандарта C++17 достаточно для компиляции как VC++, так и [G++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37c81d4835f0529d) без этого самого `<>`... Что нисколько не умаляет ценности вашего примечания, само собой...

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу @Harry:

Есть два варианта объявления и определения дружественной функции для шаблонного класса:

1. Мы можем неявно объявить шаблон функции, который должен использовать параметр, отличный от параметра шаблона класса. Данный варинат использован в примере Harry, дублировать его не буду.
2. Также мы можем предварительно объявить оператор сравнения, следовательно и шаблонный класс `CFraction`, а уже затем объявить его другом класса.

Пример:

```
template<bool reduced>
class Fraction;

template<bool F>
auto operator==(const Fraction<F>& f1, const Fraction<F>& f2) -> bool;

template<bool reduced = false>
class Fraction
{
public:
    friend auto operator==<reduced>(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2) -> bool;
};

template<bool F>
inline auto operator==(const Fraction<F>& f1, const Fraction<F>& f2) -> bool
{
    return true;
}
```

Обратите внимание:

`friend auto operator==<reduced>(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2) -> bool;`,

я указал `<reduced>` после оператора. Таким образом мы объявляем специализацию шаблона функции, которая не является членом класса, как друга.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала я выражу свое мнение относительно того, что плохо.

1. Класс не использует аргумент шаблона, и, впринципе, не сможет
   использовать воот почему:
2. Тип известен во время компиляции, и при инстанцировании шаблона,
   компилятор никак не сможет знать о сокращаемости дробей, потому что
   это задача времени выполнения.

Во время выполнения  нормальный класс должен иметь возможность изменять свои неконстантные члены, так что если дробь изначально был сокращаемым, может стать и не сокращаемым. Чтобы выразить это, лучше применить подход хранения булевского типа в конкретном классе или же  воспользоваться преимуществами наследования(первый вариант предпочтительней для данного класса).

Если все же решить впользу шаблона, то это именно тот случай, для которого используется  [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

Comment: я имел в виду, что работая с классом `Fraction<true>` я всегда буду иметь 1/2, а работая с `Fraction<false>` и 1/2 и 128/256 и т.д., т.е. после каждой операции в первом случае будет деление числителя и знаменателя на их НОД. Все остальное в классах кроме этой особенности одинаковое, поэтому и думал, что при переопределении операторов сложения и т.п. для `Fraction<true>` будет проводиться операция сокращения на НОД. По сути будет один класс с чуть разным функционалом в ряде методов в зависимости от параметра. Разве это неправильный подход?